# One method successfully toggles a control's "Enabled" property - a similar method fails. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code behind I have two method to enable or disable a group of controls depending upon the value of a field on a form.  One of these methods works as expected, and the other doesn't ... quite.  The one that works depends upon the value of a Checkbox, while the other depends upon the value of a drop-down list (I believe that this difference is irrelevant - I mention it only for completeness).  I've simplified these methods for readability, but the only significant difference from the production system is that they set a number of controls, not just one.

```
    private void SetControlsFromDropDown(int statusID)
    {
        // This method doesn't work
        bool enable = (statusID == (int)ReqStatus.CompletedOK)
        this.myTextBox.Enabled = enable;
    }


    private void SetControlsFromCheckBox(bool enable)
    { 
        // This method works
        cboMyDropDown.Enabled = enable;
    }
```

Where the first method fails is that it sets the controls correctly when the form is loaded.  However, when the drop-down list changes, the method is called and the value of the bool variable "enable" is correctly set, and the code runs through as expected (and a watch on the Enabled property of the controls that are being set shows that they are toggled as expected) - BUT BUT BUT the controls remain firmly unchanged in the interface. So, if they were initially set to Enabled = false they remain disabled even though the method might have set them to Enabled = true.

What is causing me conniptions is that if I put setting of this.myTextoxBox into the second method, it toggles correctly.

I get the impression I haven't explained myself very clearly. In essence, two more-or-less identical methods, called from similar events, operating in arguably indistinguishable ways, behave differently in real-time.  One will toggle the Enabled property of a group of controls *ad lib*., while the other will toggle it once, never to be toggled again.

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Edward

Comment: Think we need more context.  How is SetControlsFromDropDown called?  Is it called in OnInit, or during an event handler, etc.?  The event life cycle is very important, especially if you're setting Enabled after the control has already been rendered.

Comment: Both methods are called from event handlers; the checkbox from an OnCheckedChanged event, and the drop-down from an OnSelectedIndexChanged event.  I know that both methods are being correctly called because breakpoints are hit during execution.  However, I think that it's possible (though I can't quite work out how) that the non-functioning method is running after the controls have been rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a failure of the brain.  I was getting an incorrect value from the drop-down list.  Apologies for any time wasted.

Comment: You should either provide a complete answer yourself and mark it as accepted, or voluntarily delete the question that that search results are consistent for people with similar issues - as it stands though, I'd lean on the delete side, it's not incredibly clear what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about this, but try to remove the 'this'

Just put the following:

```
myTextBox.Enabled = enable;
```

Comment: In his method as shown, removing `this` makes no difference, since there is no local value named `myTextBox`.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue once, although with different controls. Although it worked the first time, the control was unable to update on postback. I did not had time to investigate the reason at the time, so i never got to know what it was, but this issue looks pretty similar!